# Move and Double click for an ImageView

Tags: android, move, touch-event, ontouchlistener, double-click

I have this problem:

I have an `ImageView` and i set it in `onTouchListener` and i'm able to move it.
The problem is that i want to set the same imageview to listen a DoubleClick event.

Do you have any examples that can help me to resolve this issue?

I need move and double tap on the same imageview!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Touch_Screen  extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private ImageView mImageView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.touch_test);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mRrootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
            mImageView = (ImageView) mRrootLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
        }
        mRrootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx very nice answare!